# Caching Application Block Error

Tags: caching-application-block

Has anyone seen this error before?

An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for cachingConfiguration: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) (C:\WorkingDir\Projects\ReportCentral\ReportCentral\bin\Debug\ReportCentral.vshost.exe.config line 5)

I am using Ent Lib 4.0. I changed my App Traget Framework from 2.0 to 3.5.

Edit ~

I have the following in the bin

Caching.dll
Common.dll
ObjectBuilder2.dll

Edit ~ "Solution"

This was the deal, when referencing dlls in the C:\EntLib4Src\bin, they are signed and could only be configured by the EntLibConfig.exe found in that same folder and not the one from "Start>Programs>Microsoft Patterns...>Ent Wasn't that tricky?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the deal, when referencing dlls in the C:\EntLib4Src\bin, they are signed and could only be configured by the EntLibConfig.exe found in that same folder and not the one from "Start>Programs>Microsoft Patterns...>Ent Wasn't that tricky?

Answer (score 2):

That means it can't find the file. So you either need to put it into the GAC or the bin folder so that the assembly can be loaded.

Comment: I have the following in the bin

Caching.dll
Common.dll
ObjectBuilder2.dll

Comment: Hmm.. I have a project with those references and I can switch between the 2.0 and 3.5 target types with no issues. I'm assuming you're abbreviating those dll names right?

Comment: This was the deal, when referencing dlls in the C:\EntLib4Src\bin, they are signed and could only be configured by the EntLibConfig.exe found in that same folder and not the one from "Start>Programs>Microsoft Patterns...>Ent

Wasn't that tricky?